# Ошибка установки модуля canvas | Nodejs

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm

Пытаюсь установить canvas через npm. Первый раз ругался на то что нет  питона 2.7
Установил питон, и конфиг. Пытаюсь установить заного но тут я уже не понял что не так. Помогите кто может см скрин ниже)

[image: Изображение]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не установлен GTK2. Попробуйте установить его вручную (шаг 2).

Ручная установка: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation:-Windows#2-installing-gtk-2